# Having trouble getting data from Splunk using rest api

Tags: api, curl, command-line-interface, splunk

I am using rest api to get the data from Splunk through command-line -interface. Below is my curl command to get the data.

```
curl  -ku  admin:pwrd https://localhost:8080/servicesNS/admin/app/search/jobs -d search="search index=policy sourcetype=smaccess source="/app/CA/log/smaccess.log" earliest=-1d | bin _time span=1d | eval date = strftime(_time, "%m/%d/%Y") | stats dc(uid) as ActiveUsers by date"
```

I'm getting below exception while trying with the above curl command.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <messages>
    <msg type="ERROR">Unparsable URI-encoded request data</msg>
  </messages>
</response>
```

It was working without this `eval date = strftime(_time, "%m/%d/%Y")`  in the search query.
Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `%` characters usually introduce a URL-encoding, but '%m', %d', and '%y' are not valid encodings.  Try URL-encoding the entire search string or at least change '%' to '%25'.

Comment: @RichG Thank you for the response. It worked for me. I tried the following Curl command:     

curl  -ku  admin:pwrd https://localhost:8080/servicesNS/admin/app/search/jobs -d search="search index=policy sourcetype=smaccess source="/app/CA/log/smaccess.log" earliest=-1d | bin _time span=1d | eval date = strftime('_time', "%22%25m/%25d/%25Y%22") | stats dc(uid) as ActiveUsers by date"